# C++ capture command line entered and output line by line

Tags: c++, loops, command-line-arguments

I'm writting a c++ program and I am looking to capture the inputs from command line. For each argument that is entered in the command line it is to be captured. The program will capture every command line until the user enters END. The program will then provide an output of each commandline argument that was entered. Example: User enters *./program* to run this program. *./program* is captured. User then enters *test* this is then captured user then enters *arg* then *END*. The program then outputs

- **./program**
- **test**
- **arg**

This is what I found for a resource I just don't know how to fully implement and loop http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DEN36Up4/
Below is what I have so far, just not sure of the for loop waiting for the END 
thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Enter your command line \n and to stop enter END" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        /* code */
    }
    // Once user types END then arguments entered in will display
    std::cout << << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you provide us with example input and output?

Comment: Sure so I execute the program. Message displays  * Enter your command line \n and to stop enter END * Then user enters in whatever into the command line such as * ./Program * so it captures that you executed the program * a.out * it would then capture this and append to the last capture -- So input 1 would be ./program  input 2 would be a.out input 3 ls test -- user enters END -- program outputs ./program "pilcrow" a.out "pilcrow" test

Comment: I'd edit the question to add that information, Bigboy6. And I'd reword it so that it's coherent.

Comment: edited it - hope it better explains my problem @user4581301

Comment: Much better. If I am reading this right, you want the command line used to execute the program as well as all input they user types in line-by-line until they type in END.

Comment: Question - it is your expectation that argc of main() be 1?

Comment: That is correct @user4581301

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [cin](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/) and [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)

Sample code (not tested):

```
string command_list;

while(true) {
    string input;
    getline (cin, input);

    if(input.compare("END") == 0)
        break;
    else
        command_list.append(input);
}
```

Comment: I recommend using `std::vector<std::string>` for the container of strings.  Appending one string to another makes searching the string for substrings difficult.

Comment: True, but since op just want to print it i think this is the best approach.

Comment: thank you @FábioJunqueira exactly what I needed and can build off of this. Really the string function and getline command were crucial. Much appreciated!